# Different url from controllername in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller called CarController located in a folder called Buy. So the url becomes www.website.com/Buy/Car

How do I make the url be instead "/purchase/vehicle" without changing controller and folder name?

Thanks!

Comment: `routes.MapRoute("buyCar", "purchase/vehicle", new { controller = "Car", action = "Buy" });`

Comment: The folder doesn't matter.  Physical folder structures do no relate to routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a new route for it

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "VehicleRoute",
        url: "purchase/vehicle",
        defaults: new { controller = "Car", action = "TheAction" }
    );
```

Just make sure you have placed it before the default route.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a custom route. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for informations about routing. You can then create your custom route with default values for the Controller and the action, something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "MyRoute",
  "purchase/vehicle",
  defaults: new { controller = "Car", action = "Buy" }
);
```

You have to put in there the correct controller name and the action you want to call.